# At what times are files updated on windows

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I have added a watcher like this:

```
        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(LOGFILES, "*.log");
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
  | NotifyFilters.FileName;

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

and there is some external application writing to log files in the LOGFILES folder. But the watcher dont seem to trigger itself for hours, then when I remote desktop to the machine and manually opens the folder I can see for my self how a file 1sec later updates the size/timestamp.

Is there any chance that the external app writing the log files first are flushing when a user actually enters the folder or what can possible cause this?

Comment: What's the context this code runs in?

Comment: Its running as administrator role (azure webrole)

Comment: looks like its first when opening the file with notepad its written to.